# An error appears: : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when calling the Change() method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a program with 2 forms (the program is connected to the MSql server database), in the first form there is dataGridView1, it displays data from the database, when I click on one of those lines in dataGridView1, a second form appears with textBoxes and all the data that was in dataGridView1 are transferred to the second form in textBoxes. so far everything is working fine. In the second form, it is possible to change the data in the textBox, after changing the data in the textBox, you need to click on the "Change" button (this button calls the Change method) and then the "Save" button (this button calls the Update method, and in this method the changed data should enter to the database) but when I click on the "Change" button, an error appears.

the code of the second form in which there is a button:

```cs
private void buttonChange2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
    mainForm.Change();
}
```

the code of the Change method, which is located in the main form (where dataGridView1 is):

```cs
public void Change()
{
    Full_Inf_Form Full_Inf_Form = new Full_Inf_Form();

    var selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; // <=== NRE exception

    var id = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxID_Inf.Text;
    var name = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStNa_Inf.Text;
    var lastname = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxLaNa_Inf.Text;
    var patr = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStPa_Inf.Text;
    var numb = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxNumb_Inf.Text;
    var email = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxEmail_Inf.Text;
    var grup = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxGrup_Inf.Text;
    var spec = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxSpec_Inf.Text;
    var data = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxDataVst_Inf.Text;
    var sypend = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStSt_Inf.Text;
    var mat = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalMat_Inf.Text;
    var ukr = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalUkr_Inf.Text;
    var eng = Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalEng_Inf.Text;
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].SetValues(id, name, lastname, patr, numb, email, grup, spec, data, sypend, mat, ukr, eng);
        dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[13].Value = RowState.Modified;
    }
}
```

the error appears in: `var selectedRowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;`

this is a method that transfers data from dataGridView1 to the textBox of the second form:

```cs
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    selectedRow = e.RowIndex;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        Full_Inf_Form Full_Inf_Form = new Full_Inf_Form();

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow];

        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxID_Inf.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStNa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxLaNa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStPa_Inf.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxNumb_Inf.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxEmail_Inf.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxGrup_Inf.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxSpec_Inf.Text = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxDataVst_Inf.Text = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxStSt_Inf.Text = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalMat_Inf.Text = row.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalUkr_Inf.Text = row.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.textBoxBalEng_Inf.Text = row.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        Full_Inf_Form.Show();
    }
}
```

I tried moving the Change method from the main form (where dataGridView1 is) to the second form, but it didn't help.
At first, I made the same program, but the textBoxes and the "Change" button were in the main program, that is, there was only one form and everything worked fine, all the data that I changed in the textBox and then clicked on the "Change" button and then "Save" got into database and everything worked fine.
But I wanted the textBoxes and the button "Change" and "Save" to be in a different form.

Comment: My guess is that there is no cell selected, so that `dataGridView1.CurrentCell` is null. Embed the code in `if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null) { ... }`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes you are right dataGridView1.CurrentCell is null but why, dataGridView1.CurrentCell should not be null

Comment: Have you selected a Cell in your UI?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes when I run the program, the main form with dataGridView1 appears, then I select a cell (click on it) and the information from the cell appears in the textBox of the second form. that is, I select a cell

Comment: @OlegLosh, step through the debugger and make sure its that line that is throwing the exception.